# Test Container test cases do not run due to "Could not find a valid Docker environment", scalatest, os x, Docker Desktop

Tags: integration-testing, scalatest, testcontainers

Trying to run integrations tests with Scalatest on my mac. Got the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

The integration tests depend on a postgres instance in a container.

I don't understand. Docker Desktop is actually started since I can even execute SQL requests in a PG container and get responses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my scala project with scalatest, testcontainers and sbt,
when using :

```
"com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala-scalatest" % "0.40.12" % IntegrationTest,
```

docker is not found.
Whereas, when using :

```
"com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala-scalatest" % "0.41.0" % IntegrationTest,
```

docker is found and the integration tests do run.

It would seem that `testcontainers-scala-scalatest` "0.40.12" is not compatible with "Docker Desktop 4.25.2 (129061)" (and probably a couple earlier versions…).
Thankfully, version "0.41.0" is compatible with current Docker Desktop.